# jQuery Cycle + Minimal Timeout

Tags: jquery, timeout, cycle

I am having a small problem with the jQuery cycle plugin and its timeout.

I am using the `scrollLeft` effect and would like to get it to always keep scrolling (similar to a news ticker if you know what I mean). Now using `timeout: 0` will not work, because it would disable the auto scolling at all.

So I thought of using `timeout: 10` (to have a almost non noticeable timeout), but this doesnt work too, because no matter how low I set the timeout, the timeout always seems to be about a second (even when using `timeout: 1`).

Again to make it a bit more clear:

Increasing the timeout to `timeout: 10000` has the desired effect and pauses the sliding for 10 seconds, but decreasing it to `timeout: 1` looks just like as if I used `timeout: 1000`

I am not sure where the problem is, because I was looking all around Google for *minimum timeout*, but couldnt find anything that said the timeout minimum is `1000`

The script I am using is very simple, so I think there should be no errors there, but just so that you can check that too I post it:

```
    $('#demo').cycle({
        slideExpr: 'p',
        fx: 'scrollLeft',
        next: '.next', 
        speedIn: 5000,
        speedOut: 5000,
        fastOnEvent: 1000,
        containerResize: 0,
        pause: 1,
        timeout: 10
    });
```

I hope I was able to explain my question well enough :)

Regards!

p.s. I dont want to use some sort of newsticker plugin, but would really like to create that effect with cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option for jQuery Cycle called [continuous](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/continuous.html) which is the closest the plugin is able to come to a traditional news-ticker. Try the following:

```
$('#demo').cycle({ 
    fx: 'scrollLeft', 
    continuous: 1
});
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: WoW! I looked through the options for almost an hour, did Google research for an hour and I simply overlooked that! Feel like an idiot now :S Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

If you need a really continuous scroll, you can use the `easeIn` and `easyOut` options. Try this:

```
$('#demo').cycle({
   fx: 'scrollHorz',
   continuous: 1,
   easeIn: 'linear',
   easeOut: 'linear'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Ignore this answer since it requires code change. Use `continuous` option as answered above.

In the buildOptions() function find the following code

```
var buffer = opts.fx == 'none' ? 0 : opts.fx == 'shuffle' ? 500 : 250;
while((opts.timeout - opts.speed) < buffer) // sanitize timeout
    opts.timeout += opts.speed;*/
```

and comment the while loop

```
var buffer = opts.fx == 'none' ? 0 : opts.fx == 'shuffle' ? 500 : 250;
/*while((opts.timeout - opts.speed) < buffer) // sanitize timeout
    opts.timeout += opts.speed;*/
```